# Object Oriented Nested Dictionary Data Structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, dictionary, plist, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm attempting to create an abstract syntax for a lisp style plist. For example:

```
(:A 1 :B (:X 3 :Y 2) :C 4)
```

Here's the grammar so far (in EBNF):

```
Plist -> { Key Value }*
Key -> string
Value -> string | Plist
```

I need to represent this data structure in C#. Unfortunately, I'm struggling to create classes for the nonterminals. This seems trivial in a dynamically typed language like python (dict with values that are either strings or dicts). But in C#, how can the user of the data structure know if a value is a plist or a string in a polymorphic way?

Here's the C# code I have so far:

```
interface Value { }

class PList : Value
{
    private Dictionary<string, Value> Dict;

    public Value this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return Dict[key];
        }
    }
}

class String : Value
{
    public string Datum { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you use object in place of value you can add a new object[]{#} or a new Dictionary as the object then you could use a recursive method to access and handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track. The pattern you are trying to use is the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). In this pattern the common behavior or a common abstraction is used for the leaves and internal nodes(both in trees and here in your example). Then the abstraction is used in the composite like so:

```
public interface IValue
{
    public void OperationOnValue();
    public List<IValue> GetChildren();
}

public class CompositePList : IValue
{
    private Dictionary<string, IValue> dict;

    public void OperationOnValue()
    {
        foreach(var things in dict)
        {}//things to do
    }

    public List<IValue> GetChildren()
    {
        return dict.Select(keyValue => keyValue.Value).ToList();
    }
}

public class StringValue : IValue
{
    private string leafValue;
    public void OperationOnValue()
    {}//thing to do

    public List<Children> GetChildren()
    {
        return null; //or return new List<Children>()
    }
}
```

With this design you can have a root `IValue` and then polymorphically call `OperationOnValue()` on it. Is there any more functionality you have in mind?

Comment: The Composite Pattern is certainly helpful. The common abstraction needs to return a string for basic values but a plist for nested values (similar to lisp's [getf](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_getf.htm)). This seems to cause an issue with the pattern. How can the operation return these different types?

Comment: The whole point of the pattern is to get away from having to return different things. You only have `IValue`s. In other words, your data structure would basically be a root `IValue` and then you would call `OperationOnValue()` to do an operation. If you have another method return the child `IValue`s you'd be able to go through the data structure without having to check for the type of `IValue`. Note that even in this scenario if you want to do something special with leaf nodes(which you do) you still need to check if `IValue is StringValue`.